# Scaffolded Yesod application with lts-7.9: `stack build` works, `stack test` works `stack exec -- yesod devel` does not

Tags: haskell, ghc, yesod, haskell-stack

I am building a simple web app (called `pkb`) with Yesod using the `yesod-simple` template. I need a bunch of libraries that don't have a recent enough version in lts-6.25 (the current default for `yesod-simple`) so I changed the resolver to lts-7.9 in `stack.yaml`. I also read [this issue with GHC 8.0.1](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12130) and successfully worked around it by adding

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoDisambiguateRecordFields #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoRecordWildCards          #-}
```

where necessary and changing any `X{..}` to explicit notation with records. Now my package builds successfully using `stack build` and the unit tests run without any problem using `stack test`. When I launch my application using `stack exec pkb` I can visit the website and everything functions fine. Loading the application in GHCi also works fine (using `stack exec cabal repl` and then typing `appMain` + [Enter] at the prompt).

Now when I try to run the development server using `stack exec -- yesod devel` (which used to work before switching to lts-7.9) I get the following error:

```
app/devel.hs:2:1: error:
Failed to load interface for ‘Application’
It is a member of the hidden package ‘pkb-0.0.0@pkb-0.0.0-6TveDldRrhNJw1vO6l4VeJ’.
It is a member of the hidden package ‘pkb-0.0.0@pkb-0.0.0-AeggierDgKl46ITEmuA1C2’.
```

Looking at the output of `stack exec -- yesod -v devel`, I can see that the `pkb` package is on the list of directories searched for. Also, all the files required to load the `pkb` package are present:

```
$ ls -l .stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-7.9/8.0.1/pkgdb
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 sam sam 5738 Nov 19 20:26 package.cache
-rw-r--r-- 1 sam sam 2536 Nov 19 20:26 pkb-0.0.0-AeggierDgKl46ITEmuA1C2.conf
$ ls -l .stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-7.9/8.0.1/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.0.1
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 6 sam sam 4096 Nov 19 20:26 pkb-0.0.0-AeggierDgKl46ITEmuA1C2
$ ls -l .stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-7.9/8.0.1/bin
total 27440
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sam sam 28094672 Nov 19 20:26 pkb
```

So why is the `pkb` package still 'hidden' according to this error message?

I have the output of the aforementioned commands [here](https://gist.github.com/SamDM/aa578351e7ee8abc810bc8e1b884a761). 
If you need more information, please let me know and I'll happily provide it.

Comment: Seeing the log you seem to have multiple version of `pkb`. Just a guess: remove `.stack-work` and try again to see if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. Now I get:
    `app/devel.hs:2:1: error:
        Failed to load interface for ‘Application’
        It is a member of the hidden package ‘pkb-0.0.0’.`

Comment: I'm not sure, what this package is. I'm not able to see it in hackage: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pkb

Comment: It the name of the application I am developing (`stack new pkb yesod-simple`). By default, the scaffold site makes a file `app/devel.hs` which imports the application you are developing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Temporary workaround:

This issue has recently been solved in the yesod code base but it is not yet in the yesod master branch. To work with `yesod devel` and GHC 8, you can do the following (for now).

1. Clone the yesod repository: https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod.git
2. Checkout the `1304-stack-based-devel` branch.
3. Run `stack install yesod-bin` inside the yesod repo. This should install the `yesod` executable. Make sure this executable is on your `$PATH`.
4. `cd` to your project folder.

   1. Run `yesod devel` inside your project (do not run `stack exec -- yesod devel`).
   2. If something fails, try the following command in your project folder to make sure no traces are left from previous builds: `rm -rf yesod-devel dist .stack-work static/tmp && stack clean && stack build` (this might be overkill, but it doesn't cause any harm so why not).

You should now be able to run the development server again.

## Some random notes:

- To launch the interactive interpreter, use `stack ghci` (not `stack exec cabal repl`).
- `stack build` and `stack test` work as before.
- The issue is tracked on the [yesod issue tracker on GitHub](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues/1304).
- Here is the [pull request](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/pull/1305) for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: have you run `stack build yesod-bin` since changing your resolver? My guess is you're running a yesod executable compiled against the older GHC version.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, yes, I did rebuild yesod-bin after switching to lts-7.9. If I execute `stack exec -- yesod version` I see: `yesod-bin version: 1.4.18.7`. Is there any way of checking this the correct version (i.e. build against GHC 8.0.1)?

Comment: What does stack exec which yesod tell you?

Comment: It says: `/home/sam/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-7.9/8.0.1/bin/yesod`. So I guess that's the correct version.

Comment: It looks like there's actually a bug with yesod-bin, which isn't too surprising since very few people would be using Yesod with GHC 8.0.1 yet. Can I recommend opening up a Github issue to continue debugging this?

Comment: Sure, I'll create an issue this afternoon.

Comment: I added the issue, see: https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues/1304 
I am a little busy at the moment. But I'll have time in a few hours in case you need anything else to work on the issue.